# Finding the average of a list in python

Tags: python, list, average

After some research of the other questions already on the site, my program is still kicking back an error. I am wanting to find the average of my list which is taken from a text file.
The text file is layed out like the following:

```
0
dyl
1
john
2
ryan
3
Chelsey
4
bob
5
dan
```

This is my code:

```
a = open("stats.txt","r")

b = a.read().splitlines()

newvar = []

newvar.extend(b[0::2])

avg = sum(newvar)/len(newvar)

print(avg)
```

The result I get is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: The error is correct - `splitlines` reads in the file contents as a list of strings. So, even if your line contained a number, because of that usage, it's actually a string. What you have to do is convert the lines containing the numbers (i.e. the even ones) into ints, and save them separately. Then you should be able to obtain the average.

Comment: What does the list `b` consist of? Integers and strings interleaved? _Nope._ You read in a file, what do you get? A bunch of bytes. It's _your job_ to handle them appropriately (i.e. convert to integers).

Comment: You could have just researched that error to find out what it means.  It's a pretty straight forward one though

Comment: Any suggestions as to how to do this? I'm new to python as a language. I come from a C# basic background where variables are clearly provided data types.

Comment: RSon I did, that was my original search. That lead me to other posts which left me confused.

Comment: You can attempt to cast something into an integer using `int(my_object)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem & Solution

The main problem with your code is that after reading your file and parsing the output, `newvar` is a list of strings:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Since `sum` will not handle strings - and even if it could, you wouldn't get your  desired output - you need to convert the strings to integers. This can be done using a simple list comprehension:

```
newvar = [int(s) for s in newvar]
```

You can then use `sum` as normal:

```
sum(newvar) / len(newvar)
```

Which has the output:

```
2
```

### Improvements

Here are some general improvements to your original code:

- Use the context manager statement `with` to open your files. That way, you can be sure your files are always closed.
- Rather than using a slice to filter out alphanumeric lines, you can use a 'filter' in the list comprehension above to skip over them.

Here is the modified code:

```
with open('stats.txt', 'r') as file:
    nums = [int(n) for n in file.read().splitlines() if n.isdigit()] 
avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)
print(avg)
```